# Creating a buffer class by extending Python str

Tags: python

I guess this is best explained by code and comments:

```
import struct

class binary_buffer(str):
    def __init__(self, msg=""):
        self = msg
    def write_ubyte(self, ubyte):
        self += struct.pack("=B", ubyte)
        return len(self)

Output
>> bb = binary_buffer()
>> bb # Buffer starts out empty, as it should
''
>> bb.write_ubyte(200)
1   # We can see that we've successfully written one byte to the buffer
>> bb
''  # Huh? We just wrote something, but where has it gone?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str`s are immutable. Therefore,

```
self += struct.pack("=B", ubyte)
```

is evaluated as

```
self = self + struct.pack("=B", ubyte)
```

This assigns a new value to the name self, but self is just a name like any other. As soon as the method exits, the name (and the associated object) are forgotten.

You want a [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray):

```
>>> bb = bytearray()
>>> bb.append(200)
>>> bb
bytearray(b'\xc8')
```

Comment: I'd say that in general, assigning to "self" is wrong. At least I can't come up with a legitimate use for this.

Comment: @doomster: Why is that? And how else would you do it?

Comment: @TahitiPetey Because you're just binding something to the name self, which is usually your current object. To change the current object, assign to one of *its* properties, or, equivalently, call one of its methods.

Comment: @phihag: So when I simply use bb, what method is it invoking to return the bytearray? Is not using self? I would like to be able to pass the binary_buffer object into a socket.sendto() method as the message. Is there a more 'pythonic' way of doing this?

Comment: @TahitiPetey `bytearray.append(x)` is (approximately) implemented as `self._bytes += x`. You can pass in a `bytearray` object to `sendto`, but you can always create an immutable bytes object from it with `bytes(bb)`.